# OpenCV on Ubuntu: I can't use video capture to read video files

Tags: opencv

I am trying to VideoCapture video files using the following code:

```
VideoCapture cap("input.avi");
if(!cap.isOpened()){
    cout << "Cannot open the video" << endl;
    return-1;
}
```

However the output is always "Cannot open the video", meaning that I can't read this video. (I am sure I put the video file in a correct deritory)

But I am able to VideoCapture from a real-time camera successfully using

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
```

Why this happens? How can I fix it because I really need to read video files instead of real-time camera.

THX!

Comment: There are just so many reasons for that to fail. It can be that `input.avi` is not in the same directory with the binary file: you can try absolute path. It can be that you don't have the proper codec on the system.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thx. I believe it can be the second reason. So I installed another version of ffmpeg and it works finally....